# Variable in Constructor of Class Template

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I'd like to realize something like this (basically an object to be a specific class of a class template depending on some other variable):

```
const auto object = (a == 0) ? std::make_unique<MyClass<X> >(...) 
                             : std::make_unique<MyClass<Y> >(...);
```

I know that this clearly does not work and I also guess I know why, but do you see any way to work around this?

EDIT:

`<MyClass<X>` and `<MyClass<Y>` do not derive from the same base class currently.

I put different function definitions for `X` and `Y` in there, for example, I'd simply want to call

```
object->callFunction();
```

at some other point and of course get different results if it's either `X` or `Y`.

Would it work to make like a dummy base class to let `<MyClass<X>` and `<MyClass<Y>` derive from, and then just set `object` to that and redefine the object afterwards depending on the condititions?

EDIT2:

Well, it works like I wanted it to, but it's still anything but aesthetic. Thank you though.

Comment: `object` must have some type, known at compile time. You can't magically give it different types based on a runtime condition. Is there any relationship between `MyClass<X>` and `MyClass<Y>`; e.g. do they derive from a common base class? How do you plan to use `object` once initialized? Show a [mcve]

Comment: `std::variant<std::unique_ptr<MyClass<X>>, std::unique_ptr<MyClass<Y>>` is also an alternative to base class.